# A random point $(a,b)$ is uniformly distributed in a unit square $K=[(u,v):0<u<1,0<v<1]$

Tags: probability

A random point $(a,b)$ is uniformly distributed in a unit square $K=[(u,v):0<u<1,0<v<1]$
Let $n$ be the number of real roots of the polynomial $f(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^3 - a^2 x +b$.Find the probability $P(n=3)$.
I am failing to understand the criteria of choosing $(a,b)$ so that $f(x)$ has three real roots.

Comment: Hint: You want to contrast having three real roots with having one real root and two complex roots (there may be other unlikely possibilities, but they will turn out not to matter).  Perhaps you could consider the signs of $f(x)$ when $f'(x)=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph of $f$ is a cubic parabola. We have three real roots of $f(x)=0$ iff $f$ has a local maximum and a local minimum, and if the values of $f$ at these two points have different sign. From
$$f'(x)=x^2-a^2$$
we can conclude that the two local extrema exist at $\pm a$ as required. Furthermore
$$f(a)f(-a)=\left(b-{2\over3}a^3\right)\left(b+{2\over3}a^3\right)\ .$$
You now have to analyze how the sign condition for this product partitions the unit square $K$.The probability you are after is the area of one part of this partition.

Comment: OK, done! Good one